# Best practices to use MDB pool with some types of message

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

Whats the best practices to use MDB with several types of message, use several queues, one queue to one type of message, or use one queue to all types with different activation specification selector and type in message header?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are (as with anything) some trade-offs to think about:

Having a queue perform a single, well-defined function promotes good encapsulation, and allows your application to be as flexible and well encapsulated as possible.  This would raise possibilities such as queue-specific thread pooling, so you can dedicate more resources to one message type, or ensure that long-running requests of once type don't block more urgent requests of another type.

On the other hand, adding a queue uses system resources, so having too many queues may be inefficient (although you'd need a *lot* before this is noticeable), or confusing if it makes it difficult to identify the correct queue for a particular message type.

One EIP which is worth considering is the [command pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CommandMessage.html) - this uses a single queue to perform multiple actions.  It's also worth bearing in mind the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) - even if your application is internally using a number of different queues, you might prefer to use a facade to present this from client systems.